# matlab gui togglebutton stop while loop

Tags: matlab, user-interface, while-loop

I am having trouble stopping execution of a while-Loop which is activated by pressing a Togglebutton and is meant to stop when the Togglebutton is "untoggled".

The code inside calls a function that causes a steppermotor connected to an Arduino to do one step. The function needs about 10ms to execute.

Stopping works fine if i add a pause after the function call, but as the Onestep-function already needs longer to execute than I wish for and minimum pause-time is 10ms this solution isn't really pleasing.

```
% --- Executes on button press in Aplus_button.
function Aplus_button_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
while get(hObject,'Value')
    Onestep(1, 'Motor', handles)
    % if i add a pause() here it works
end
```

I am thankful for any hints on how I get this executed as fast as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding a call to `drawnow` in your loop, where you have the pause. This should poll the GUI for any changes in state.

Since your `Onestep` function is so quick, you might only want to call `drawnow` only every 10th iteration (for example), depending on the GUI lag you can tolerate.

Answer (score 0):

```
function button1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to while_button1 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
q=0;
while  get(hObject,'value')
    drawnow
    q=q+1
end
```